# Choosing array size for known number of keys in seperate chaining using mod method

Tags: hash-tables

If we know the number of keys that we are going to get ,how do we calculate the size of the array we will need to store our separate chains in the hashtable?

All that using the mod hashfunction

Comment: Storing $n$ keys requires memory which is $n$ times the size of a single key. Is that the kind of formula you're after? Otherwise, explain what you mean by "the size of the array we will need to store our separate chains".

Comment: we've been given a task to create a hastable array whose elements are pointers to chains , and we are asked to store keys on these chains using the key values,we are only given the number of keys that are going to be given and we are asked to use the mod method to chose which key goes to what list,but we are not given the size m of the array ,we are asked to find it